# javafx Option doesnt appear in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I just install eclipse on a new PC. It is the latest Version from June 2019. As I do it multiple times before I install "e(fx)clipse" to use javafx and Scenebuilder.
normally now I can go to Window --> Preferences --> Javafx, but the last option doesn't exist.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall "e(fx)clipse" as well as eclipse it self (In between I restart the System several times). 
I don't have any further Ideas and the Internet not provide a working Solution.

I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here :)

greetings

Comment: What java version did you install?

Comment: I install java 8 openjdk (https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases/tag/1.8.0.212-1)